# selenium: wait for element to be clickable not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to use expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable but it doesn't appear to be working. I'm still seeing "Element...is not clickable at point" errors in about 30% of the runs.

Here's the full error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown
>   error: Element ... is not clickable at point (621, 337). Other
>   element would receive the click: ...
>         (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.90)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436421 (6c1a3ab469ad86fd49c8d97ede4a6b96a49ca5f6),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6
>   x86_64)

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
def wait_for_element_to_be_clickable(selector, timeout=10):
  global driver
  wd_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)

  wd_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)),
    'waiting for element to be clickable ' + selector)
  print ('WAITING')
  return driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
```

Update:

So now this is really odd. Even if I add a couple of fixed wait periods, it still throws the error message occasionally. Here's the code where the call is being made:

```
  sleep(5)
  elem = utils.wait_for_element_to_be_clickable('button.ant-btn-primary')
  sleep(5)
  elem.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is stated in the error message.

> Element ... is not clickable at point (621, 337). Other element would receive the click: ...

The problem is that some element, the details of which you removed from the error message, is in the way... on top of the element you are trying to click. In many cases, this is some dialog or some other UI element that is in the way. How to deal with this depends on the situation. If it's a dialog that is open, close it. If it's a dialog that you closed but the code is running fast, wait for some UI element of the dialog to be invisible (dialog is closed and no longer visible) then attempt the click. Generally it's just about reading the HTML of the element that is blocking, find it in the DOM, and figure out how to wait for it to disappear, etc.

Comment: One would think that the function would take that into consideration when making the isClickable determination. I ended up creating my own function that catches the exception and performs retries.

Answer (score 6):

Ended up creating my own custom function to handle the exception and perform retries:

```
""" custom clickable wait function that relies on exceptions. """
def custom_wait_clickable_and_click(selector, attempts=5):
  count = 0
  while count < attempts:
    try:
      wait(1)
      # This will throw an exception if it times out, which is what we want.
      # We only want to start trying to click it once we've confirmed that
      # selenium thinks it's visible and clickable.
      elem = wait_for_element_to_be_clickable(selector)
      elem.click()
      return elem

    except WebDriverException as e:
      if ('is not clickable at point' in str(e)):
        print('Retrying clicking on button.')
        count = count + 1
      else:
        raise e

  raise TimeoutException('custom_wait_clickable timed out')
```

Comment: your function work! but I have to change wait(1) to time.sleep(1). Can you explain where is the wait(1) come from?